# Which Javascript solution(Not .htc) can really make Antialiased round corner in IE7 and 8?

Tags: css, xhtml, cross-browser, rounded-corners

Which JavaScript solution (Not `.htc`) can really make Anti aliased round corner in IE7 and 8 like `CSS3` gives in supported browsers?

I tried many

http://www.ruzee.com/blog/ruzeeborders/

http://blue-anvil.com/archives/anti-aliased-rounded-corners-with-jquery/

http://www.curvycorners.net/

All are claiming to give anti aliased corner but giving corners like this

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/375652/11063104941-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/375652/11063104941-My-Desktop.png)

But no one is giving anti aliased corner. if I need `10px` round corner.

Comment: @Assaf Lavie - if we will use image then element will not be flexible in height and width.

Comment: Even if you use larger rounded-corner images which are shrunk to size in CSS? That would probably survive zoom-in by the user...

Comment: but htc is some kind of js though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly make flexible elements with image round corners.

See [this article](http://home.tiscali.nl/developerscorner/liquidcorners/liquidcorners.htm).

Because CSS3 border-radius is now supported in many of the modern browsers, you could use that as your primary solution and provide a fallback for the ones that don't support it.

On a recent project, I created the website with border-radius and used the jQuery .wrap() for browsers that didn't support it. It looks something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="round">
    <p>Hi, I'm a paragraph</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.round {
    border: 1px solid red;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
    $('.round').wrap('<div class="tl"><div class="tr"><div class="bl"><div class="br"></div></div></div></div>');
}
```

And you can then style the round corner elements as per the article above.

Comment: Have you styled the round corners? You still need to use images for IE. You've applied everything correctly, you just need to style the round corners now (and remove the 1px red border programatically for IE because it will get replaced by the image round corners)

Comment: just for example i styled round corner with background color and height temporarily. and it should work, positioning is not related to images.

Comment: I see what you mean - I've added a <div class="content"></div> where the content gets injected. Previously the content was being added to one of the round corners. Also there is now a relatively positioned parent. check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/9AyJy/4/

Comment: ok. we can also do in this way http://jsbin.com/oweka3/16

and i need border because i'm making round corner with `1px` border

Comment: Yeah - but you probably want to make the border part of the rounded corner images and disable the CSS border in jQuery (as per my jsFiddle).

Comment: I need to make round box like this http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=8786248

And i think in ur jsfiddle example you are adding 2 extra div `<div class="wrapper"><div class="content">` We can strip these 2 div and use this way http://jsbin.com/oweka3/16

Comment: Yep you can append it too - that will work as well! Looking good - now just replace them with images :)