# Why CSS making links non-clickable in Firefox?

Tags: css, xhtml

**I'm checking in Firefox 3.6**

Why **2nd level** links are not clickable in this tab menu.

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/383239/11061405615-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/383239/11061405615-My-Desktop.png)

**live example here :** http://jsbin.com/upeka4/5

these are clickable if disable the css

Comment: As far as I can tell all links are clickable (they all change color as though I have visited them), could you be more specific. (For the record I'm in IE7)

Comment: Are you using a specifc browser? Or do you see this happen in all? Because as @Alex said they seem to work for me. I see a # sign in the url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because the `z-index` definition here:

```
ul.level2  {
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #F3F8C6;
border:1px solid #EABF4A;
left:0;
padding:6px;
position:absolute;
top:30px;
width:463px;
z-index:-1; <------------------------ there
}
```

Comment: but without it i can't make overlap effect without using images.

Comment: if i remove z-index or set to 1 then Active tab will look like this http://shup.com/Shup/383241/1106141035-My-Desktop.png. which i don't want

Comment: @metal Give the level2 a `z-index` of `0` and the element above it `1`. I think the problem here is the negative z-index.

Comment: @Pekka i want to make tab like this http://stashbox.org/952395/11061405615-My-Desktop.png with cross browser compatibility

Comment: See my comment in my answer as it should guide you to a non-image solution to your problem.

Comment: @Pekka - give answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154949/how-to-make-overlap-tab-effect-without-using-image

Comment: @Pekka - no not working it's giving this output http://shup.com/Shup/383241/1106141035-My-Desktop.png

Comment: @metal try this. http://jsbin.com/upeka4/8 tested only in Firefox but seems to work there at any rate. Need to get back to work, but maybe it helps.

Comment: Not too difficult, the styling for the tab needs to move to the `a` tag so that the `z-index` can be used to overlap the `ul`. Again, see my comment under my answer for a few more details. The point is, to get the `z-index` to work, you have to be working with the two items that are under the first level `li`, which is the `a` and the `ul` tags. The `a` is the only option for using as overlap to the border of the second level `ul`.

Comment: @Scott I think that's pretty much what I did in the jsbin example. Same idea at the same time. :)

Comment: @Pekka - Thanks for effort it's working well in Firefox but in IE 7 , this is the result http://shup.com/Shup/383253/11061412012-My-Desktop.png

Comment: @metal seems to be the white spaces between the `<li>`s. This seems to work except for a double border: http://jsbin.com/upeka4/9/# that is probably easy to fix.

Comment: @Pekka - thanks working now. yes IE showing double line and it can be solved to give `top:27px` in conditional css.

Comment: @Pekka - one more thing i will use this method to make tab's corner round http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170402/which-javascript-solutionnot-htc-can-really-make-antialiased-round-corner-in-i/3173643#3173643. will it work ? because to use this i will have to use `position:relative` on tab's 1st level `li`

Comment: @metal I can't say really. It *should* work as far as I can see but no guarantees.

Comment: @Pekka - "@metal seems to be the white spaces between the `<li>`s. This seems to work except for a double border: jsbin.com/upeka4/9/# that is probably easy to fix." but i noticed now links not working again jsbin.com/upeka4/9/#

Comment: @metal strange, all the work seems to have been reset on jsbin! Revision 9 is gone, it contained comments from me. Sorry, I can't re-fix that right now. Did it work yesterday?

Comment: @pekka - "@metal seems to be the white spaces between the `<li>`s" what you were saying in this?

Comment: @metal strange, this isn't working any more - it did yesterday :) I'm stumped what the problem is!

Comment: @pekka - http://jsbin.com/upeka4/8 it was working in FF but in IE http://shup.com/Shup/383253/11061412012-My-Desktop.png. i need tab like added in my question 2nd level links should be clickable in FF.

Answer (score 4):

Your `z-index: -1` is the problem

Comment: You mention wanting the 'overlap' effect. I recommend reworking your styling on the `a` tag (border, margin, padding) to make it 'fill' the `li` and match it to what you have on the `li` (lose the `li` styling), and then set it's bottom border color to match the background color and then 'lift' it with a `z-index: 1` to have it cover the top border of your secondary `ul`. I don't have time right now to rework the code for you.

Answer (score 2):

change the z-index for the ul.level2 from -1 and you should be good to go. IE will still allow them to be clicked but firefox doesn't usually allow it if there's an element on top of them.

Comment: but i want to make overlap tab effect , and without z-index it's not possible with pure css

Answer (score 0):

Others above have explained the problem. For a solution, just do:

```
#tabcontainer
        {
          height:32px;
          position:absolute;
          margin: 2em;
          font-size: 12px;
        }
```

Reducing the height to 32px causes the secondary links list to "overflow" out of the tabcontainer and therefore is not covered by it (though it's still displayed "below" it according to the z-index). `position:absolute;` causes the secondary links to only be positioned below the tabcontainer, not below any parent elements (like html, body).